# Expectation of $S$ where $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_{i}$

Tags: statistics, expected-value, statistical-inference

Consider a collection of $N$ cards numbered $1,2,...,N,$ where $n\geq 3$. Two cards are drawn at random and set aside. Suppose $n$ cards are selected at random from the remaining $(N-2)$ cards using SRSWR and their numbers are notes as $y_1,y_2,...,y_n$. If $S=\sum_{i=1}^{n}y_i$ then $E(S)=\frac{N+1}{2}$.

I am almost clueless in this problem. I know the definition of expectation but not able to prove it using only definition. Kindly tell if I need to know something more (may be some theorems)

I am new to Statistics.

Comment: I think that you might have mixed up $n$ and $N$.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming that your $n=N$).

Suppose that the values of the two cards drawn aside are $X_1$ and $X_2$. Then when you draw a card at random from the remaining $N-2$ cards, its value has a uniform distribution over the set $\{1,2,\dots,N\}\setminus \{X_1,X_2\}$. So the expectation of $Y_i$ is given by
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_i\mid X_1,X_2)=\left[\frac1{N-2}\cdot 1+\frac1{N-2}\cdot 2+\dots+\frac1{N-2}\cdot N\right] - \left[\frac1{N-2}\cdot X_1+\frac1{N-2}\cdot X_2\right]
=\frac1{N-2}\cdot \left[\frac{N(N+1)}2-X_1-X_2\right].
$$
Now,
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_1)=\frac1{N}\cdot 1+\frac1{N}\cdot 2+\dots+\frac1{N}\cdot N=\frac{1+2+\dots+N}{N}=\frac{N+1}2
$$
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_1)=\left[\frac1{N-1}\cdot 1+\frac1{N-1}\cdot 2+\dots+\frac1{N-1}\cdot N\right] - \frac1{N-1}\cdot X_1
$$
so
$$
\mathbb{E}(X_2)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(X_2\mid X_1)=\left[\frac1{N-1}\cdot 1+\frac1{N-1}\cdot 2+\dots+\frac1{N-1}\cdot N\right] - \frac1{N-1}\cdot\mathbb{E} X_1
=\frac{1+2+\dots+N-\frac{N+1}2}{N-1}=\frac{N+1}2
$$
which you can alternatively get by symmetry (it does not matter which of the two was drawn first).

Finally, Ssnce $Y_1,\dots,Y_n$ are i.i.d.,
$$
\mathbb{E}(Y_i)=\mathbb{E}\mathbb{E}(Y_i\mid X_1,X_2)=\frac1{N-2}\left[\frac{N(N+1)}2-(N+1)\right]=\frac{N+1}2
$$
(not surprisingly again, because of symmetry).

Comment: if we assume n=N, then how can N numbers be chose from N-2 numbers

Comment: SRSWR means "Simple random sampling with replacement" which means that you select a card an put it back. Hence you can select *any* number of the cards (more than N)

Comment: Hi, could you explain the first step: why's E(Yi| X1, X2) the difference of those values?

Comment: The set of remaining $N-2$ cards is $\{1,2,\dots,N\}\setminus\{X_1,X_2\}=\{1,2,\dots,X_1-1,X_1+1,X_1+2,\dots,X_2-1,X_2+1,X_2+2,\dots,N\}$ (the second equality assumes that $X_1<X_2<N$). Hence the sum of values of $N-2$ cards is $1+2+\dots+N-(X_1+X_2)$.